# How does one build and submit a form that works in all modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, cross-browser, form-submit

I'm using JavaScript to submit a form that I make from scratch.  The code below works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE.  How can I make and submit a form and have it work across 'all' browsers?

```
function someFunction(){
    var SomeForm = document.createElement("form");
    addInputFieldToForm("SpecialName_SortField","UpdateDate",SomeForm);
    addInputFieldToForm("SpecialName_SortOrder","false",SomeForm);
    addInputFieldToForm("Operation","Search",SomeForm);

    SomeForm.action = "<%=link("direct", "WorkspaceDisplay") %>"; // assume this URL is valid (it is).
    SomeForm.method = "post";
    SomeForm.target = "_top";
    SomeForm.submit();
}

//EDIT: Added this function to the question just so there's less mystery (not because it matters, really)
function addInputFieldToForm(elementName, elementValue, theForm) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.name = elementName;
    inputElement.value = elementValue;
    inputElement.id = elementName;
    theForm.appendChild(inputElement);
}
```

Comment: What does "addInputFieldToForm" do?  That would probably be the code of interest. What you're trying to do is pretty common and not browser-sensitive, or at least it shouldn't be.

Comment: are you using any js framework? you should if you want to create cross-browser compatible form from scratch. anyway, what exactly doesn't work? can you provide any error msgs from firebug?

Comment: The "doesn't work" part is just that the form doesn't post.  The server logs didn't move.  The JavaScript apparently was running, but "SomeForm.sumbit();" didn't submit the form.  The problem was addressed in Rob W's answer, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append the form to the document before it can be submitted.
If you don't want to change the UI, you can apply a style to the form.

```
var SomeForm = document.createElement("form");
SomeForm.style.display = "none";             // <-- Invisible form
document.body.appendChild(SomeForm);         // <-- Append <form> to body
// Rest of code ...
```

Side note: You're using `SomeForm` as a variable name. It's a perfectly valid JavaScript variable, but agaist the conventions. Camel-cased variables should only be used to name constructors, e.g. `Array`, `Object`, `MyClass`.